# Error in MongoDB query with $and command: db.users.find({$and:[{$text:{$search:"England -UEFA"}},{$text:{$search:"Euro 2016}}]}).count()

Tags: mongodb-query, bigdata

The database used is sample. Collection used in users. `text` is a index created for attribute `tweet_text`.

```
db.users.find({$and:[{$text:{$search:"England -UEFA"}},{$text:{$search:"Euro 2016}}]}).count()
```

I wish to know the reason for error code. Also, the correct code for query to find data in `tweet_text` having "England" but not "UEFA". Further, from those filtered data, how many data exists for `tweet_text` having "Euro 2016". The query for the same I have mentioned above.